AWS Cognito - How to generate a report of userpool based on custom attributes
We have just migrated to Cognit for our site users (roughly 600,000 users).
How would I go about generating a report of users based on custom attributes? I can see I can search via a limited set of fields (Username, Email, First name, Last Name, Phone Number, User ID(Sub), Confirmation Status). However, there is no way to search using the custom attributes.
What would be the best solution to doing this?
and what about searching via multiple custom attributes?
Any help is greatly appreciated.
